# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, python-module

I am trying to import a package. And when it is imported, it seems to be working, i can use its elements, but, i get an error still that says that there i no package named after what i imported. the error is this:

```
from database import DataBase
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

I think people would try to suggest to do

```
pip install databases
```

in to the terminal, and i have done that, and i have also done these in to the terminal as well just incase:

```
pip install databases[postgresql]
pip install databases[mysql]
pip install databases[sqlite]
```

And it just does not seem to work.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing an "s" in ```from database import DataBase``` ?

Comment: You're installing a module named `databases`, then you're trying to import from a module named 'database`. Those are different names.

Comment: @Tibbles the thing is, i am using pycharm, it comes up with the module name as that when i try and type it in. But ill try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work - note that Database is case sensitive. You can see the docs and some examples [here](https://www.encode.io/databases/).

```
from databases import Database
```