# Encountered an error setting up ORM ormar

Tags: python, database, fastapi, ormar

Started learning fastAPI and when setup ormar. I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 62, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 390, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1456, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 397, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 278, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 23, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/bob/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/bob/practice/pythonProjects/fastapi/./main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from db import database, metadata, engine
  File "/home/bob/practice/pythonProjects/fastapi/./db.py", line 1, in <module>
    import databases
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'databases'
```

I find this [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973983/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-database). but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

According to the readme https://github.com/collerek/ormar Ormar is built using

```
sqlalchemy core for query building.
databases for cross-database async support.
pydantic for data validation.
typing_extensions for python 3.6 - 3.7
```

Your error implies that `databases` is not installed on your system and therefore has to be installed in order for the library to work.

Install it via `pip3 install databases` (or `pip`)

Comment: I try to install but I got this:
Requirement already satisfied: databases in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy<1.4 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from databases) (1.3.23)

Comment: Did you install it with `pip` or `pip3` ? Try running `pip3 list | grep databases` and let me know if it returns something

Comment: @isabi. I tried both.  pip3 list | grep databases >>> databases          0.4.3

Comment: Are you running it with `venv`?

Comment: Then you should enter the `venv` environment, install it there and then run the program. Did you do that?